# Get values separated by br, after an element

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<div class="unique_class"> 
<h2>
    ...
</h2>
<h2>
    ...
</h2>
<strong>
    unique strong before content
</strong>
</br>
static title 1: value 1
</br>
static title 2: value 2
</br>
static title 3: value 3
</br>
static title 4: value 4
</br>
</br>
</div>
```

I need to get those 4 values using JSOUP.
They are always after the 'strong' tag, and are separated by br tags. How to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Document doc = // ... eg. parse File / String here or connect to a website
Node value;

for( Element element : doc.select("strong ~ *") )
{
    // element.previousSibling() is possible too
    value = element.nextSibling();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

This will print:

```
 static title 1: value 1 
 static title 2: value 2 
 static title 3: value 3 
 static title 4: value 4
```

*(And two more lines with a single ' ')*

Comment: Unfortunately using toString() method from Node object returns the value encoded (ã = &atilde;).
I think the ideal solution would be using text() method from Element object, but I'm not seeing a way to do it...

Comment: using this worked: ((TextNode) element.nextSibling()).getWholeText()